# Choosing values for epsilon in limit and convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

In studying proofs for limit theorem I ran into this:

Theorem: If the sequence $(S_n)$ converges to s and k is in R, then the sequence $(ks_n)$ converges to $ks$. That is, $lim (ks_n) = k*lims_n.$

Proof:
We assume  $k \neq 0$ since this result is trivial for $k=0$. Let $\epsilon >0$ and note that we need to show $|ks_n-ks| < \epsilon$ for large n. Since $lim s_n = s$, there exists N such that $n>N$ implies $|s_n-s|<\frac{\epsilon}{|k|}$. Then $n>N$ implies $|ks_n -ks| < \epsilon$.

My question is: how did they decide on $|s_n-s|<\frac{\epsilon}{|k|}?$ 
I understand they need to satisfy $|ks_n-ks| < \epsilon$ to prove $lim (ks_n) = k*lims_n.$

But on what basis did they decide to divide $\epsilon$ by $|k|?$ It would make sense to me if $|ks_n -ks| < \epsilon$ came first and $|s_n-s|<\frac{\epsilon}{|k|}$ followed it, but it seems to me as if they pulled $|s_n-s|<\frac{\epsilon}{|k|}$ out of thin air.

Comment: You *want* $\lvert ks - ks_n \rvert < \varepsilon$, and you get to *choose* $\varepsilon'$ such that you'll get $\lvert s - s_n \rvert < \varepsilon'$. Since $\lvert ks - ks_n \rvert = \lvert k\rvert\cdot \lvert s - s_n \rvert$, to achieve what you want, taking $\varepsilon'$ such that $\lvert 
k\rvert\varepsilon'=\varepsilon$ makes sense. (It is not "out of thin air," but indeed the choice comes *after* going through and realizing what you want, and what you can achieve.)

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you.